# How do i get Process.MainMoudle.FileName?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace HardwareMonitoring
{


    public class GetProcesses: IWin32Window

    {
        internal IntPtr handle;
        internal String title;
        internal String filename;

        public IntPtr Handle
        {
            get { return handle; }
        }

        public String Title
        {
            get { return title; }
        }

        public String FileName
        {
            get { return filename; }
        }

        public static readonly Int32 GWL_STYLE = -16;
        public static readonly UInt64 WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000L;
        public static readonly UInt64 WS_BORDER = 0x00800000L;
        public static readonly UInt64 DESIRED_WS = WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE;

        public delegate Boolean EnumWindowsCallback(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 lParam);

        public static List<GetProcesses> GetAllWindows()
        {
            List<GetProcesses> windows = new List<GetProcesses>();
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(100);
            EnumWindows(delegate(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 lParam)
            {
                if ((GetWindowLongA(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & DESIRED_WS) == DESIRED_WS)
                {
                    GetWindowText(hwnd, buffer, buffer.Capacity);
                    GetProcesses wnd = new GetProcesses();
                    wnd.handle = hwnd;
                    wnd.title = buffer.ToString();
                    windows.Add(wnd);
                }
                return true;
            }, 0);

            return windows;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern Int32 EnumWindows(EnumWindowsCallback lpEnumFunc, Int32 lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern void GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, Int32 nMaxCount);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern UInt64 GetWindowLongA(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nIndex);
    }
}
```

And in form1:

```
foreach (var wnd in GetProcesses.GetAllWindows())
            {

            }
```

With wnd I can get the handle and titles of the processes but i need to get also the FileName.

If I was doing:

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
```

Then I could do:

```
p.MainModule.FileName
```

How can I get the FileName property with in my class ? I add there the property but how to get it the value ?

EDIT

In the class bottom I added:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);
```

Then in the class i used it:

```
wnd.processid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(wnd.handle, IntPtr.Zero);
```

And in form1:

```
    string ff = "";
    void PopulateApplications()
    {

        foreach (var wnd in GetProcesses.GetAllWindows())
        {
            uint uuu = wnd.ProcessId;
            ff = Process.GetProcessById((int)uuu).MainModule.FileName;
        }
    }
```

But when it's doing the line:

```
ff = Process.GetProcessById((int)uuu).MainModule.FileName;
```

It does nothing but exit the program. No errors or exceptions.

EDIT

In the class bottom:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hwnd, out int ID);
```

Then using it in Form1:

```
    int ff = 0;
    List<string> FileNames = new List<string>();
    void PopulateApplications()
    {

        foreach (var wnd in GetProcesses.GetAllWindows())
        {
            GetProcesses.GetWindowThreadProcessId(wnd.handle, out ff);
            FileNames.Add(Process.GetProcessById(ff).MainModule.FileName);
        }
    }
```

I'm getting only 18 processes FileNames.

Comment: Process.GetProcesses() returns too many processes.  You'll also get the ones that throw an exception when you use the MainModule property.  Like the System process, it is not a real process and does not have a MainModule.   Just don't use it, EnumWindows() already gives you what you need.  Pinvoke GetWindowThreadProcessId() to obtain the process ID of the process that owns the window.  Process.GetProcessById() next.   If you are trying to re-invent Task Manager then keep in mind that it runs elevated.

Comment: Hans i'm not going to use the GetProcesses but when I did use it I could do this: var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName); so I wonder how can I do it now when using the EnumWindows()

Comment: I explained how you can use Process.GetProcessById().  Try it.

Comment: Tried to do it, I edited my question with what I did and I see in form1 on the variable uuu that the id number change each loop but when it's getting to the line FileName it's just quit the program and does nothing.

Comment: You are not using GetWindowThreadProcessId() correctly.  It returns the thread ID of the thread that owns the window.   You need to use the 2nd argument.  Declaration is wrong, that 2nd argument must be `out int pid`.  Error checking is required.

Comment: Hans edited my question is that correct ? I'm getting only 18 processes. And if I wanted to get the processes like in task manager ? Is it hard to do ?